# HTTP/1.1 504 timeout response

Tags: php, timeout, wampserver

I run a program which downloads data from a site and save it in a folder with file_get_contents. Simultaneously I insert the data (title etc) in my mysql database. Suddenly one day my program stopped and returned me this "The web service endpoint returned a "HTTP/1.1 504 Timeout" response". I use wampserver (PHP). Does anyone know how to fix this?
Thank you.

Comment: Ask the web service endpoint I guess? It's an error returned by the web site you're querying. There may be nothing you can do on your end to fix it (although it could also be a proxy problem on your end, if you are behind a proxy).

Comment: You were right. It was not my fault. It was caused due to server overloading. It was fixed by itself and now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP code is executing something in a loop or fetching data from the web server and has not responded back with any data. While your web server waiting for PHP to respond the request timeout was reached.

The best way to debug this issue is going through step by step in the specific script and add breakpoints to debug.

If you use a remote debugger supported IDE then you can easily do this within your IDE.

Zend Studio is easy to setup and get running.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I want my program to run continuously (background) and I can not use break points. It was running fine for a month so I do not think it has to do with the code. Is there a way to extend my request timeout?